# Image from url-Where did i go wrong?

Tags: java, android, image, url, inputstream

### This is what this piece of code is supposed to do.

When the button is pressed, it is supposed to take the current image, and replace it with the one in the url that is in the string "finalurl"

### What it does

It takes the current image and just makes it dissappear. It does not replace with any other image. Ive been stuck on this for a few days and im stumped. Any help is appreciated.

Here is the code i used.

```
public void firstbutton(View view) 
    {
        Context context = view.getContext();
        Drawable image = ImageOperations(context, "@string/finalurl","image.jpg");
        ImageView icon = new ImageView(context);
        icon = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        icon.setImageDrawable(image);

};


private Drawable ImageOperations(Context ctx, String url, String saveFilename) {
    try {
        InputStream is = (InputStream) this.fetch(url);
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src");
        return d;
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

public Object fetch(String address) throws MalformedURLException,IOException {
    URL url = new URL(address);
    Object content = url.getContent();
    return content;
```

}

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11441198/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-an-image-from-url-to-imageview-in-android/11441358#11441358

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This.

```
Drawable drawable = LoadImageFromWebOperations(ImageLink);
        imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);


  private Drawable LoadImageFromWebOperations(String url)
    {
          try{


        InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
        return d;
      }catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exc="+e);
        return null;
      }
    }
```

Comment: I see what i did wrong. The url that i fed to the ImageOperations method wasnt a url. I actually gave it "@string/finalurl" and it tried to pull an image from something that doesnt really exist. Thanks for your help!